# Error java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

Getting error while connecting to node.js from android socket programming. I'm using socket.io for connecting to server but time out is occurring again and again , Any help will be appreciated

Code

```css
   SocketIO socket = new SocketIO("http://10.10.10.125:1337");  
     socket.connect
       (
         new IOCallback(){
          @Override
          public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
           System.out.println("an Error occured");
           socketIOException.printStackTrace();
          }
          @Override
          public void onDisconnect() {
           System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
          }
          @Override
          public void onConnect() {
           System.out.println("Connection established");
           //socket.send("Hello Server!");
           //System.out.println("send msg to server");
          }
          @Override
          public void onMessage(String arg0,
            IOAcknowledge arg1) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           System.out.println("Server said: " + arg0);
          }
          @Override
          public void onMessage(JSONObject arg0,
            IOAcknowledge arg1) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           try {
            System.out.println("Server said:" + arg0.toString(2));
           } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
          }
          @Override
          public void on(String arg0, IOAcknowledge arg1,
            Object... arg2) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           System.out.println("on....");
          } 

         }
         );
      

      } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
       e1.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Error

```css
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986): io.socket.SocketIOException: Error while handshaking
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:322)
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  at io.socket.IOConnection.access$600(IOConnection.java:39)
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:199)
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986): Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:544)
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:784)
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:313)
12-04 16:30:30.510: W/System.err(8986):  ... 2 more
```

Comment: how do you define your socket? post your code for that part please.

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani I have updated code now please check ...

Comment: what is your server's socket.io version and which library are you using for android client?

Comment: I'm using socketio.jar

Answer (score 1):

the problem is your client library supports socket.io 0.9.x and your server is using socket.io v1 and from 0.9 to 1 , handshake protocols changed in socket.io library. try downgrading your server's socket.io to 0.9 and it'll work without any problem or you can use [socket.io-client](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java) that supports socket.io v1.0.x

Comment: Can u please suggest me any ways to upgrade client library instead downgrading my serve's .

Comment: @Aman see my updated answer and accept it if it helped you for solving your problem :)

Comment: There is no jar or lib in that, please suggest how to use it

Comment: it's for new android project structure that uses maven. are you using eclipse?

Comment: Yes i'm using eclipse